# Can we ask questions about games that haven't been "released" but are under Steam Early Access?

Tags: discussion

Title says it all.  I've been kinda curious about those games now that Steam has the feature which allows for early access to games.

Comment: This is concerning games that are under development, thus categorized as "not released", yet you can play them, so they should be counted as a "release"

Comment: Technically, Minecraft is still in beta, and Dwarf Fortress didn't have an official release, and both are still under development.  Do those count as, "Not released"?

Comment: @fbueckert Minecraft no longer is in beta. ;) But for that matter, all *publically playable* versions of a game qualify as a *demo*, *beta* or, well, *actually released* in regards to on-topic-ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.